# Readme file created in GIT remote shows up as a separate branch

Tags: git, github

I uploaded my java project and later added a Readme file from the online GIT at the remote. This created a separate branch and the only file I see in the branch is the "readme" file. I later realized that while creating the readme file there was an option at the bottom of the editor which says to directly merge with main or create a separate branch. I think I selected the latter causing a separate branch. Now I went ahead and created the same readme file again and merged directly onto the master. I now need to know how to delete the unnecessary branch called "main" which just has this incorrectly created readme file. Please see the screen shots below.
[image: Screen1 - showing separate branch with just the readme file]
[image: Screen2 - showing the actual master branch were I added readme again]

Please let me know how to delete the branch that just has the readme file alone. I tried `git pull origin master` and it did not work. I got the message something like merging unmatched history etc.

Comment: [Of Git and GitHub, master and main](https://www.biteinteractive.com/of-git-and-github-master-and-main/)

Comment: Search "How to delete a branch from GitHub?", shouldn't really be difficult. In any case, instead of re-creating the readme, you could have cherry-picked the commit into whichever branch you would like it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only the default branch has the "readme" file that got incorrectly created, and there is no delete option there

Probably because it is the default branch.

You can [change the default branch first](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/configuring-branches-and-merges-in-your-repository/managing-branches-in-your-repository/changing-the-default-branch) to the one with your code, and then delete the wrong branch (with the `README`)

Note that the default GitHub branch is now "`main`" ([since Oct. 2020](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-10-01-the-default-branch-for-newly-created-repositories-is-now-main/), as explained [in renaming](https://github.com/github/renaming/)).

A `git config --global init.defaultBranch main` (as [shown here](https://gist.github.com/plembo/57c18254d6d9a8301e8ee3c83da089c8)) would ensure your own local repositories are created by default with the same branch name.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click on the branches and you will be able to click the delete icon.

[image]

I hope this helps you

Comment: I saw this option earlier, but I need to only delete the branch with just the "readme" file . 
I saw the following in that view :
1. Default branch
2. Your branch
3. Active branch
Both 2 & 3 has my code. Only the default branch has the "readme" file that got incorrectly created, and there is no delete option there